# Netbeans won't let me add GlassFish server

Tags: netbeans

When adding another server in Apache Netbeans 8.2 I get this error Not a valid GlassFish Server installation, what can I do?
I need to add another GlassFish server to run a connection pool which also gives me a 500 error

Delete apache? check plugins?